# Is it possible to use VPN on the PI using WLAN?

Tags: vpn

I plan to buy raspberry pi model A+. I can initially have an HDMI Monitor and keyboard, but then I plan to just remotely connect to the desktop there, using VPN software (e.g. tightVPN). What I have seen is people using this configuration with the network being a LAN one, but can this also work using WLAN? I don't see a reasone why it shouldn't but just want to make sure before buying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can this also work using WLAN?

There's no difference on the application level between ethernet and wifi, so yes, if you can do it one way, you can do it the other.